# Android MIC events or broadcasts

Tags: android, sdk, microphone

I writing the app with MIC using. And I want to know that someone takes MIC ( viber, skype, regular call... ) to avoid trying to use mic if it is busy now. Can I get some info about this ? Something like broadcast or something?